# Check if form file exists on page load using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, forms, file, get

So I have a simple form that takes a user input, passes it to a separate PHP script that does some processing on a different domain, and posts a txt file if successful.  Example:

```
<form method="GET" action="inventory_check.php" target="_blank">
    Part Number <input type="text" name="part" /><input type="submit" value="Check Inventory" />
</form>

<?php
$filename = $userInput;

if (file_exists('ftpMain/'.$filename.'')) {
    $handle = fopen("ftpMain/".$filename."", "r");
    $output = fread($handle, filesize('ftpMain/'.$filename.''));
    fclose($handle);
    $output = trim($output, '&l0O(10U');
    $output = trim($output, 'E ');
    echo $output;
} 
else {
    echo 'Failure.';
}
?>
```

So, inventory_check.php obviously is an inventory lookup for us, however, it's contained on another server (different domain) so it completes its processing and posts it to a file, that I read, cleanup, and display.  Now my issue is twofold, I need to grab and keep the input from the user to find the filename and the second is I need to page to either reload or recheck if the file exists.  What is the best approach to do this?

Note:  We use an awful in house DBMS, so posting and retrieving from a DB is not an option, it took us a while to get it to read the input and FTP it correctly, so it looks like this is the only path.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make the request in your server A? by using curl, so you could get the response right after the query.

Comment: Could you explain a little further...sorry I'm not too informed on PHP

Comment: instead of sending the form to another domain, send it to another php file in your same domain, and inside this file you make a request direct to the other domain, so you can grab the output right after the script finish.

Comment: take a look at this 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php|
you use this to post to the other server inside your script

Comment: can you give me an example of the curl function with something being posted (or preferably using GET)?

Comment: If you're using GET you could use file_get_contents
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

like

$content = file_get_contents('htp://url?params=param');

the $content will get the output from the url, so you could change it to instead of generating a file, directly print it

Comment: Thanks, well day is over so I'll be testing tomorrow...I'll let you know how things turn out.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll need to get the user's input properly, and sanitize it. I'll leave out the details of the `sanitize()` method, as that's not really what you're asking.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)) {
    $part_number = sanitize($_POST['part']);
    $filename = "ftpMain/$part_number";
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $output = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);
        /* Do things with output */
    } else {
        echo 'Failure.';
    }
}

?>
```

However, you say that the file is on another server - looking for `ftpMain/...` is only going to look for a directory called `ftpMain` in your current directory. Is the file publicly available on the internet? If it is, you could do something like this:

```
<?php

$url = "http://yourserver.com/parts/$part_number.txt";
$response = get_headers($url, 1);
if ($response[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
    /* The file exists */
} else {
    /* The file does not exist */    
}

?>
```

I hope I've understood your question correctly - this assumes that the form action is pointing to itself. That is, your file with this code is also called `inventory_check.php`.

Comment: The form action is pointing to a php script on our web server.  Contained within that script is a redirect that points to our in house server and does the processing.  So basically I need it to perform that in the background, or recheck if the file exists after the processing is complete.